# How to Displaying Auto-Generated Reference Number on Google Form Submission Page

Tags: javascript, google-forms

I am working on a Google Form where I've implemented a script to auto-generate a reference number upon form submission. Currently, the reference number is visible only in the Excel sheet. I want to display it on the submission page itself.

Here is my current script

```js
function onFormSubmit(e) {
  // Get the active spreadsheet and the responses sheet
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = spreadsheet.getSheetByName('Form Responses 1'); // Change 'Form Responses 1' to the actual sheet name

  // Get the last row
  var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow();

  // Generate a reference number (you can customize the format)
  var referenceNumber = 'PRE-' + (lastRow - 1); // Adjust as needed

  // Set the reference number in the next available cell in the last row and in the first column
  sheet.getRange(lastRow, 1).setValue(referenceNumber);
}
```

How can I modify this script or implement additional steps to ensure that the reference number is displayed on the submission page instead of just in the Excel sheet?

Any help or guidance would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!"

Answer (score 0):

`onFormSubmit` runs when a user [responds to a form](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable#event-driven_triggers); that is, when the user submits the form.

In short, you cannot display the reference number on the submission sheet.